# Malformed query when creating and then looking up `ContentDocumentLink` via the new Composite Graph API

Tags: composite, graph

With the new Composite Graph API (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_graph_introduction.htm)

we are trying to create a ContentVersion, ContentDocument and ContentDocumentLink in one go and then look the data up

**IMPORTANT** I do not want to use another API, i already use it with success, for this use case I NEED to use the Composite Graph API (so i can submit some 450 other sObjects AND an attachment).

I assemble the graph like so

```
{
    "graphs": [
        {
            "graphId": "g1",
            "compositeRequest": [
                {
                    "url": "/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/ContentVersion",
                    "body": {
                        "attributes": {
                            "type": "ContentVersion"
                        },
                        "Description": "Marketing brochure for Q1 2011",
                        "Title": "Marketing Brochure Q1",
                        "PathOnClient": "Marketing Brochure Q1.pdf",
                        "VersionData":"d2hhdGV2ZXIgYmluYXJ5IGRhdGEg"
                    },
                    "method": "POST",
                    "referenceId": "reference_file_0"
                },
                {
                    "url": "/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/@{reference_file_0.id}",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "referenceId": "reference_file_lookup"
                },
                {
                    "url": "/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/ContentDocumentLink",
                    "body": {
                        "ShareType": "I",
                        "ContentDocumentId":"@{reference_file_lookup.ContentDocumentId}",
                        "LinkedEntityId":"<SOME VALID ID HERE>"
                    },
                    "method": "POST",
                    "referenceId": "reference_file_link_0"
                },
             {
                    "url": "/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/ContentDocumentLink/@{reference_file_link_0.id}",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "referenceId": "reference_link_lookup"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This fails on the last request `reference_link_lookup` with the following

> Implementation restriction: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator.

> errorCode MALFORMED_QUERY

However, if i remove the `reference_link_lookup` from payload, and i use the returned CDL URL directly:

`/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/ContentDocumentLink/<valid CDL id here>` I can see the data just fine.

Is this a known issue?